# openssl EVP_CipherFinal_ex failed

Tags: c, openssl, aes, encryption-symmetric, evp-cipher

I got this below function `file_encrypt_decrypt` for encryption and decryption of a file using AES256 CBC [from here](https://github.com/kulkarniamit/openssl-evp-demo/blob/master/openssl_evp_demo.c).

If I'm doing encryption and decryption both from same program, (main function given at the end) encryption and decryption is working properly. Though both the time same function is called and ctx is initiated again.

If I'm commenting the encryption part, passing the above created encrypted_file, decryption is failing with error: 
**ERROR: EVP_CipherFinal_ex failed. OpenSSL error: error:06065064:lib(6):func(101):reason(100)**
[[meaningful]] **OpenSSL error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt**

Somewhere people are talking about some padding length issue. But I can't figure it out properly.

Also how the same function is working properly if encryption is done at the same program but separately, it is failing?

Some guidance will be appreciated.

PS: Instead of a common function, I've tried separate functions for encryption and decryption with `EVP_DecryptInit_ex()`, `EVP_DecryptUpdate()`, `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex()` and similar for encryption but of no effect.

**Full Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

#define ERR_EVP_CIPHER_INIT -1
#define ERR_EVP_CIPHER_UPDATE -2
#define ERR_EVP_CIPHER_FINAL -3
#define ERR_EVP_CTX_NEW -4

#define AES_256_KEY_SIZE 32
#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16
#define BUFSIZE 1024

typedef struct _cipher_params_t{
    unsigned char *key;
    unsigned char *iv;
    unsigned int encrypt;
    const EVP_CIPHER *cipher_type;
}cipher_params_t;

void cleanup(cipher_params_t *params, FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp, int rc){
    free(params);
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
    exit(rc);
}
void file_encrypt_decrypt(cipher_params_t *params, FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp){
    // Allow enough space in output buffer for additional block 
    int cipher_block_size = EVP_CIPHER_block_size(params->cipher_type);
    unsigned char in_buf[BUFSIZE], out_buf[BUFSIZE + cipher_block_size];

    int num_bytes_read, out_len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if(ctx == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CTX_NEW);
    }

    // Don't set key or IV right away; we want to check lengths 
    if(!EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, params->cipher_type, NULL, NULL, NULL, params->encrypt)){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CipherInit_ex failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CIPHER_INIT);
    }

    OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(ctx) == AES_256_KEY_SIZE);
    OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(ctx) == AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    // Now we can set key and IV 
    if(!EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, params->key, params->iv, params->encrypt)){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CipherInit_ex failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CIPHER_INIT);
    }

    while(1){
        // Read in data in blocks until EOF. Update the ciphering with each read.
        num_bytes_read = fread(in_buf, sizeof(unsigned char), BUFSIZE, ifp);
        if (ferror(ifp)){
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fread error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, errno);
        }
        if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, out_buf, &out_len, in_buf, num_bytes_read)){
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CipherUpdate failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CIPHER_UPDATE);
        }
        fwrite(out_buf, sizeof(unsigned char), out_len, ofp);
        if (ferror(ofp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fwrite error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, errno);
        }
        if (num_bytes_read < BUFSIZE) {
            // Reached End of file 
            break;
        }
    }

    // Now cipher the final block and write it out to file 
    if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(ctx, out_buf, &out_len)){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CipherFinal_ex failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CIPHER_FINAL);
    }
    fwrite(out_buf, sizeof(unsigned char), out_len, ofp);
    if (ferror(ofp)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fwrite error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, errno);
    }
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *f_input, *f_enc, *f_dec;

    // Make sure user provides the input file 
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s /path/to/file\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    cipher_params_t *params = (cipher_params_t *)malloc(sizeof(cipher_params_t));
    if (!params) {
        // Unable to allocate memory on heap
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: malloc error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return errno;
    }

    // Key to use for encrpytion and decryption 
    unsigned char key[AES_256_KEY_SIZE];

    // Initialization Vector 
    unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

    // Generate cryptographically strong pseudo-random bytes for key and IV 
    if (!RAND_bytes(key, sizeof(key)) || !RAND_bytes(iv, sizeof(iv))) {
        // OpenSSL reports a failure, act accordingly 
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: RAND_bytes error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return errno;
    }
    params->key = key;
    params->iv = iv;

    // Indicate that we want to encrypt 
    params->encrypt = 1;

    // Set the cipher type you want for encryption-decryption 
    params->cipher_type = EVP_aes_256_cbc();

    // Open the input file for reading in binary ("rb" mode) 
    f_input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!f_input) {
        // Unable to open file for reading 
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fopen error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return errno;
    }

    // Open and truncate file to zero length or create ciphertext file for writing 
    f_enc = fopen("encrypted_file", "wb");
    if (!f_enc) {
        // Unable to open file for writing 
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fopen error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return errno;
    }

    // Encrypt the given file 
    file_encrypt_decrypt(params, f_input, f_enc);

    // Encryption done, close the file descriptors 
    fclose(f_input);
    fclose(f_enc);

    // Decrypt the file 
    // Indicate that we want to decrypt 
    params->encrypt = 0;

    // Open the encrypted file for reading in binary ("rb" mode) 
    f_input = fopen("encrypted_file", "rb");
    if (!f_input) {
        // Unable to open file for reading 
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fopen error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return errno;
    }

    // Open and truncate file to zero length or create decrypted file for writing 
    f_dec = fopen("decrypted_file", "wb");
    if (!f_dec) {
        // Unable to open file for writing 
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fopen error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return errno;
    }

    // Decrypt the given file 
    file_encrypt_decrypt(params, f_input, f_dec);

    // Close the open file descriptors 
    fclose(f_input);
    fclose(f_dec);

    // Free the memory allocated to our structure 
    free(params);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code generates a new key and a new IV with *each* run. So if only the encryption part is commented out, then two *different* key / IV pairs are generated and used for encryption and decryption, which leads to the observed error message. If for testing purposes a fixed key / IV pair is used instead of the each time freshly generated pair, the code works as expected.

In general, the key / IV pair used for encryption must also be used for decryption. Regarding the IV, in practice a *random* IV is usually generated during encryption. After its use, it's simply added in front of the ciphertext (since the IV isn't secret), so that it can be reconstructed and used during decryption.

Comment: Sorry For that common copy paste code. I was using a static pair of key and IV generated from static key_data and salt with `EVP_BytesToKey()`.

But that was having a different issue. I was using `strncpy` to copy the static data from a string but was using a format specifier of `%ld`. fixing that, fixed my issue. But I'm still confused regarding how the static copy was getting impacted because of enable or disable of decryption.

anyway, this answer is similar to my fix so accepting it.